# Networking Library in C++14

Tags: c++, networking, standards, c++14

Herb Sutter writes [here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/trip-report-iso-c-spring-2013-meeting) (on his ISO C++ Spring 2013 meeting trip report) that a networking library is planned to be added to C++14.

What features would this library have initially? What is it based on? Is there a proof-of-concept implementation? My Google-fu must be seriously lacking, because I can't even find the proposal draft.

There are a series of blog posts on http://meetingcpp.com/ listing the proposals for C++14: [part 1](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/a-look-at-cpp14-papers-part-1.html), [part 2](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/a-look-at-c14-papers-part-2.html), [part 3](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/a-look-at-c14-and-beyond-papers-part-3.html) and [part 4](http://meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/a-look-at-c14-and-beyond-papers-part-4.html). Among all these, I can only find two network-related proposals:

- **N3555 - a URI Library for C++** (sorry, no link; though its predecessor is [N3507](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3507.html).)
- [**N3603 - A Three-Class IP Address proposal**](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3603.html) (with a related earlier paper [N3565 - IP Address Design Constraints](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3565.pdf).)

Is this all? Will *the* C++ network library have only these facilities? I don't even know whether these passed the vote or not, as Michael Wong's [two](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/the_view_from_c_standard_meeting_april_2013_part_1?lang=en) [part](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/the_view_form_the_c_standrd_meeting_april_2013_part_2?lang=en) review of the same meeting (Bristol, April 2013) doesn't even mention them.

Comment: P.S. I believe this question should have the tag `c++14` instead of `c++1y`, but that tag doesn't exist and I don't have enough reputation to create it.

Comment: If I had to guess, the networking lib will borrow its design heavily from Boost asio. I hope, though, that they make some more scalable choices to allow for high-performance use cases.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Well, I hope they base it on some stable design that has been in use for some time (e.g. Boost.ASIO,) but what I'm asking here is what they are actually doing! But IMO, ASIO is solving a problem different from networking; namely *asynchronous I/O*, that can be applied to network programming as well. For what it's worth, I'd be happy even if they wrapped up POSIX socket interfaces and standardized that (well, not really, but close;) as long as they do something about networking in C++!

Comment: Note that there is a [development site](http://cpp-netlib.org/) for this networking library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> a networking library is planned to be added to C++14.

A networking library (or set of library components) will appear as a separate Technical Specification, not as part of C++14.

> I can only find two network-related proposals

The blog posts don't list all the proposals in the mailings, just the ones someone has found time to write up, there are others such as:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3360.pdf
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3374.htm
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3388.pdf
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3389.pdf
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3565.pdf
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3620.pdf

What will be part of the TS isn't decided yet AFAIK.

Comment: If you're happy with this answer you should [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/someone-answers) so it doesn't show up as "unanswered" in the [tag:c++1y] category