# C++ and network sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, standards

I have dabbled in C, and I am currently picking up C++.

I want to learn the standard library (`std::` namespace), so I am working on a few projects.  One is a simple email program that logs into my local SMTP server and shows my email, and has the ability to send mail.  I add a touch of ncurses for that old feel.

The problem is, I haven't been able to find a standard library way to use network sockets.  It seems like I have to use network sockets in C `sys/socket.h`, but then I end up with a file descriptor, which leaves `read()` and `write()` and `send()` function calls.  I wanted to be able to use the `std::fstream` or `std::ostream` classes.  But the `open()` member functions take a filename, not a file descriptor.

I know that the Boost library has this capability, but templates and such are way over my head, and I want to stick with just the standard library for now.

Before I proceed, I just want to make sure that there isn't a better way to `read()` and `write()` to a file descriptor that's been returned by the `connect()` network socket C function.

Comment: Could you post some example code showing how you are trying to get this to work, and maybe what does work but is not `std::`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using C socket APIs in C++ for this (I do it all the time). How do you think everyone else's socket libraries are implemented? Everything ultimately has to go through the socket APIs that are provided by the OS, and in C/C++ the BSD-style socket functions (`connect()`, `send()`, `recv()`, etc) are portable across most platforms.  Things like Boost.ASIO, ACE, CURL, etc are built on this.  And `SMTP` is not that hard to implement using C socket functions.

Comment: Your question is about C++, not C. Please don't tag spam...

Comment: As of 2019, you can use the [kissnet](https://github.com/Ybalrid/kissnet) library, which wraps socket.h (and winsock.h on Windows), and has secure sockets via OpenSSL.

Answer (score 5):

The standard library does not contain sockets or any networking support.

Your choices are

1. BSD sockets, if you are on *nix via OS specific libraries
2. BSD blocking sockets, if you are on Windows, via Winsock
3. Async sockets, if you are on Windows, via Winsock and the Windows Message Pump
4. IOCP, if you are on Windows, via Winsock
5. Boost ASIO, which is portable.
6. Some other 3rd party library where someone else used one of the above and wrapped it up for you.

Of all of those, it is my personal opinion that, Boost ASIO is the easiest to use. I would recommend at least going through a tutorial on blocking BSD sockets though to get the concepts down.

All of these, except 5 and 6, are going to be very C like. Network programming really isn't a niche where object orientated programming and C++ rule over old C style. You can wrap things, but that's the best you can hope for.

You really won't be using fstream or ostream in your socket code. Perhaps in a layer above it, but in the end, all these implementations are similar, in that you will be sending and receiving bytes of binary data or text.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not correct at all. C++ has shipped with a proper production-quality networking library since c++ 11, and in C++ 17 it's officially part of the standard library.

Comment: News to me. Name it / Link it. My Google search yields nothing at all. I fancy myself pretty up to speed on C++11. C++17 not so much.

Comment: C++11 **DOES NOT** include a standard networking library. C++ compiler vendors may include their own libraries, but networking will not be part of the standard library until at least C++17 (see [N4656: Working Draft, C++ Extensions for Networking](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4656.pdf)).

Comment: As I thought. Thanks for clarity.

Comment: Even though Bjarne stroustrup mentions it in almost every CPPCon presentation going back the last 5 years...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289923/networking-library-in-c14

The name changes between older versions of compilers, but it can be found in libstdc++ and libc++

Comment: Sorry Remy, but you're wrong. While it's not a "Standard Library" library, there's been a common one across compilers since Clang 3.2 and GCC 5.0. And in fact Bjarne's told people to use it at several presentations.

Comment: @Patrick Again, Name it / Link it. There has been _talk_ about it for decades. There have been _proposals_. There has not been any inclusion of networking support in the C++03, 11, or 14 standard. If you can show me code that performs networking while linking to nothing but the CRT on all compilers officially supporting C++14, I will Fed Ex you a 6-pack today.

Comment: #include <experimental/networking> from GCC 5 onward, Clang 3.2 onward, Visual Studio 2012 onward, and while I can't find any older documentation, at least ICC 15. You really should keep up better.

You can find the full API for it here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4656.pdf

Comment: Experimental is _not_ standard and is not guaranteed to ever be standard. It is, by its very definition "Experimental." I do no, nor should I, keep up on every proposal that made its way to experimental. I program real production code and answer questions for other professionals who also program real production code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std:::istream` and `std::ostream` with sockets, you just have to write your own (or find a pre-existing 3rd party) custom [`std::basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf)-derived class that uses socket I/O instead of file I/O, and then you can assign an instance of that class to `std::(i|o)stream` via its constructor or [`rdbuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) method.

Comment: Ever tried to write one? It's possible, but extremely difficult, and none of the streams documentation will actually tell you how to do it.

Comment: Is this really practical for someone who says "templates and such are way over my head"? He's looking for a pre-existing library, which makes it off-topic here.

Comment: You don't need to know template programming to derive a `streambuf` class.  Deriving classes is at the hard of C++ programming, so it is a good skill to learn. Besides, I did say "or find a 3rd party class".  There are socket `streambuf` classes available, such as [this one](http://www.edm2.com/index.php/Adding_socket_support_to_the_iostreams_hierarchy)

Comment: Just wondering. My brother, who is no chump, did it about 25 years ago and he said it was one of the worst experiences of his career. The `std::stream` classes were clearly not designed or documented to be subclassed or extended and just form a monolothic block. It all came down to implementing a single `reset()` method somewhere which did both input and output depending on the weather! But I can't agree for a moment that 'deriving classes is at the hard end of C++ programming', except in the case of poorly-designed class hierarchies like this.

Comment: It also doesn't buy you very much. You surely wouldn't want to use the abused << and >> operators for formatted data on a socket, and the only other thing you really gain is the rudimentary EOS and error handling.

Comment: @EJP you don't have to subclass the streams themselves, just the streambuf (and yes, I have written custom streambuf classes, just not for sockets). I didn't mean "the hard end of C++", that was a typo, I meant "the heart of C++" instead. And why not use use formatted data on sockets? A lot of Internet protocols are text-based, or at least have textual elements to them. I've seen tons of examples of people formatting `std::string` values to send over sockets, so a stringbuf that flushes to a socket can be very useful.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it, my bro. kindly told me, and once again that fact isn't documented anywhere, let alone how to do it and what you do and don't need to override. Very curious omission really.

Comment: @EJP: see [A beginner's guide to writing a custom stream buffer (std::streambuf)](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf) and [Deriving from std::streambuf](https://artofcode.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/deriving-from-stdstreambuf/).